# For the performance is better two functions in the same setInterval() or two different setInterval ? - Javascript

Tags: javascript, performance, setinterval, user-experience

For the performance is better two functions in the same `setInterval()` or each function in different setInterval() ?

**A**

```
setInterval(function(){ 
 one();
 two(); 
}, 60000);

function one(){
 //code
}

function two(){
 //code
}
```

**B**

```
setInterval(function(){ 
 one();     
}, 60000);

setInterval(function(){      
 two(); 
}, 60000);

function one(){
 //code
}

function two(){
 //code
}
```

What do you suggest ?
Thanks a lot...

Comment: "What do you suggest ?" Measure it.

Comment: how ? please...

Comment: Do you have any idea how much code a CPU can run in 60 seconds? Do you think one or two intervals/functions calls make a difference?

Comment: my code has 4000 lines so one or two intervals/functions (that makes operation on a ul list with 1000 <li> elements) could be important.

Comment: *"my code has 4000 lines"* then refactor. Simplify things. Get rid of unnecessary stuff and code duplications... *"so one or two intervals/functions (...) could be important."* not in the slightest *"(that makes operation on a ul list with 1000 <li> elements)"* so that's the real bottleneck, the code inside the functions. *Is it a bottleneck?* Maybe when/how often you call these functions is another topic, but definitely not wether you call these two functions in one interval or in two seperate ones. **This is a pointless nano-optimization**

Comment: why is pointless ?

Comment: Because it is not 1 or 2 timers that matters, it is how you deal with your 1000 `li` items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For the performance is better two functions in the same setInterval() or each function in different setInterval() ?

There are few points of view on performance.

From the **performance of those two functions**, it is faster to call `setInterval()` just once, it is faster to call function `one()` then `two()` from the context of anonymous function rather then from timing event context. And it is also worth mentioning, that those two functions might be inlined/merged together with a JS compiler or JS JIT.

From the **user experience** point of view, it better to split long functions into two, so user interface events get processed in between those functions. In other words:

1. Process user events (say, mouse clicks).
2. Call long function `one()`.
3. Process user events again.
4. Call long function `two()`.
5. Process user events.

will be much better for user experience than:

1. Process user events.
2. Call huge combined function `one()` and `two()`, hanging browser for a noticeable period.
3. Process user events.

And the last point. From the **overall performance of the program**, it does not matter at all, since the interval between those calls so long, so it does not make any difference for the overall performance.